# How to return error from asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have a function written in a file.

```
async myfunction() {
  try {
    const data = await achievementService.stepsPerDayAchievement()
    console.log(data)
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

I call another function from here which is written in another file called achievement.

```
  async stepsPerDayAchievement(user, stepsCount) {
    try {
      await ApiCall()
    } catch (err) {
      return err
    }
  }
```

But when I return err from this function it suppose it as function return and I get the error in `data`. What I need here is when I throw error from 
the `stepsPerDayAchievement` function it goes to the error part in my first file of `function`

Can someone please help what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Your `stepsPerDayAchievement` function is *swallowing* the error. You need to either re-throw it if it occurs or not add `try/catch` at all within it. Adding `try/catch` signals that you expect an error and you can handle it appropriately. If you don't re-`throw` the error afterwards, then that function call is considered green (non-errored) hence it doesn't trigger any `catch` from calling code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to throw an error from the **stepsPerDayAchievement** method:

```
  async stepsPerDayAchievement(user, stepsCount) {
    try {
      await ApiCall()
    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  }
```

this way it will land in the catch block of the calling function.

Answer (score 3):

Since async functions return promises you don't need try catch block in stepsPerDayAchievement function. I think your code should be like below:

```
async myfunction() {
    const data = await achievementService.stepsPerDayAchievement()
    .then(()=> console.log(data);)
    .catch(()=> console.err("error");)
}

 async stepsPerDayAchievement(user, stepsCount) {
      var apiCallResultData = await ApiCall();
      return apiCallResultData
  }
```

Comment: Sorry it was an async function. I have edited the question